# Why is the AC voltmeter showing zero volts in this inverter?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, diodes, inverter, proteus

I used [this video](https://youtu.be/8jsNRKTOfT4) and created this, in Proteus:

[image]

[image]

When I run it I get zero AC volts:

[image]

But the video is showing this:

[image]

Why is the AC voltmeter showing zero volts in this inverter?

Comment: Simulators can be finicky with self-starting circuits such as oscillators and inverters, in part because many self-starting circuits initially start up from natural noise/fluctuations that aren't modeled by many simulators. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the details of Proteus to advise further. Can you get a transient voltage graph, or somehow perturb it with a small pulse of series voltage/parallel current to get it to start up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TO-92 2N4410 is nothing like a 2SC2625, which is a large 10A/400V power transistor in a massive TO-247 package. You also wired it incorrectly (resistor in series with collector rather than base).

And the transformer model you used probably does not include saturation so it won't work even if those things are fixed. This kind of crude oscillator depends on transformer saturation to work. So it's not oscillating. Which means no output. This kind of circuit is deceptively simple and getting it to oscillate may take a bit of effort.

Not sure what's going on with what looks like a switch shorting out the power supply.

P.S. Notice how the person who made the video laid out the parts so that the power supply is on the left and the output is on the right. That's how your schematic should look. It's not a functional issue, but it makes the schematic easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Why does your circuit show a short circuit across the power supply when the switch is on: -

[image]

This has got to be a show-stopping error.